Django messages showing up from models.py
Now I am trying to build messaging functionality into my webapp, where businesses can message buyers and users can message sellers.
The messaging functionality works fine, but the problem is, debug django messages show up such as Message from john to steve in Lululemon, from models.py str method.
Now I don't know how to get rid of these messages for this view or why this is happening.
My models.py:
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='sent_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='received_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Message from {self.sender} to {self.recipient} in {self.business}'

    @property
    def sender_is_business(self):
        return self.sender.business.exists()

    @property
    def recipient_is_business(self):
        return self.recipient.business.exists()

My views.py:
@login_required
def message_seller(request, business_slug):
    business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            Message.objects.create(
                sender=request.user,
                recipient=business.seller,
                business=business,
                content=content
            )
            return redirect('message_seller', business_slug=business.business_slug)

    # Mark messages as read for the current user and business
    Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business).update(is_read=True)

    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
        Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
    ).filter(business=business).order_by('timestamp')

    individual_business_message_counter = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business, is_read=False).count()
    context = {
        'business': business,
        'messages': messages,
        'individual_business_message_counter': individual_business_message_counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/message.html', context)


@login_required
def message_buyer(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
    business = Business.objects.filter(seller=request.user).first()

    if not business:
        return redirect('user_messages')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            Message.objects.create(
                sender=request.user,
                recipient=user,
                business=business,
                content=content
            )
            return redirect('message_buyer', username=user.username)

    # Mark messages as read for the current user and buyer
    Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, sender=user).update(is_read=True)

    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(sender=request.user, recipient=user) |
        Q(sender=user, recipient=request.user)
    ).filter(business=business).order_by('timestamp')

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'messages': messages,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/message_buyer.html', context)

@login_required
def user_messages_view(request):
    businesses = Business.objects.filter(
        Q(messages__sender=request.user) | Q(messages__recipient=request.user)
    ).distinct()

    user_messages = []
    latest_messages = []

    for business in businesses:
        if request.user == business.seller:
            # Query messages for business with other users
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=business.seller) | Q(recipient=business.seller)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp')
            for user, chat in itertools.groupby(messages, lambda m: m.recipient if m.sender == request.user else m.sender):
                last_message = next(chat)
                unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=business.seller, sender=user, business=business, is_read=False).count()
                user_messages.append({
                    'business': business,
                    'last_message': last_message,
                    'user': user,
                    'unread_count': unread_count,
                })
                latest_messages.append(last_message)
        else:
            last_message = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
                Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp').first()
            unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, sender=business.seller, is_read=False).count()
            user_messages.append({
                'business': business,
                'last_message': last_message,
                'unread_count': unread_count,
            })
            latest_messages.append(last_message)

    # Sort user_messages by the latest message timestamp
    user_messages = sorted(user_messages, key=lambda um: um['last_message'].timestamp, reverse=True)
    
    unread_message_counter = sum(msg['unread_count'] for msg in user_messages)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        business_slug = request.POST.get('business_slug')
        business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            if request.user == business.seller:
                # Business sending message to user
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                if username:
                    recipient = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
                    Message.objects.create(
                        sender=request.user,
                        recipient=recipient,
                        business=business,
                        content=content
                    )
                    return redirect(f'{request.path}?business_slug={business.business_slug}&username={recipient.username}')
            else:
                # User sending message to business
                Message.objects.create(
                    sender=request.user,
                    recipient=business.seller,
                    business=business,
                    content=content
                )
                return redirect(f'{request.path}?business_slug={business.business_slug}')

    selected_business = None
    selected_user = None
    messages = []
    if 'business_slug' in request.GET:
        business_slug = request.GET.get('business_slug')
        selected_business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        if request.user == selected_business.seller and 'username' in request.GET:
            # Query messages for selected_business with selected_user
            username = request.GET.get('username')
            if username:
                selected_user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
                messages = Message.objects.filter(
                    Q(sender=selected_user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                    Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=selected_user)
                ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')
        else:
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')

        Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=selected_business).update(is_read=True)

    context = {
        'user_messages': user_messages,
        'selected_business': selected_business,
        'selected_user': selected_user,
        'messages': messages,
        'unread_message_counter': unread_message_counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/user_messages.html', context) 

My urls.py:
    path('message/<slug:business_slug>/', views.message_seller, name='message_seller'),
    path('message/buyer/<str:username>/', views.message_buyer, name='message_buyer'),
    path('messages/', views.user_messages_view, name='user_messages'),
    path('messages/<slug:business_slug>/', views.user_messages_view, name='user_messages_with_slug'),

I even tried using a context_processor to get rid of django messages for this view only, but did not work:
def custom_messages(request):
    excluded_paths = ['/messages/', '/messages/']
    if request.path not in excluded_paths:
        return {'messages': get_messages(request)}
    return {'messages': []}

My user_messages.html:
<main class="content mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container p-0">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3">Your Messages</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-3 border-right">
                    {% for message in user_messages %}
                        {% if message.user %}
                        {# Handle display user_messages for business with other users #}
                        <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}&username={{ message.user.username }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                            {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}
                                <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ message.unread_count }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                                <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ message.user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                    {{ message.user.username }}
                                    {% if message.last_message %}
                                    <div class="small {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}font-weight-bold{% endif %}">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                            {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}
                                <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ message.unread_count }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                                <img src="{{ message.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                                <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                    {{ message.business.business_name }}
                                    {% if message.last_message %}
                                    <div class="small {% if message.unread_count > 0 %}font-weight-bold{% endif %}">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <hr class="d-block d-lg-none mt-1 mb-0">
                </div>
                {% if selected_business %}
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-9">
                    <div class="py-2 px-4 border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center py-1">
                            {% if selected_user %}
                            {# Handle display selected_user #}
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ selected_user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_user.username }}" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ selected_user.username }}</strong>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ selected_business.business_name }}</strong>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div class="chat-messages p-4">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            {% if message.sender == request.user %}
                            <div class="chat-message-right pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    {% if request.user == selected_business.seller %}
                                    <img src="{{ request.user.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ request.user.business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="User Avatar" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">You</div>
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="chat-message-left pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    {% if selected_user %}
                                    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ selected_user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_user.username }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">
                                    {% if selected_user %}
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ selected_user.username }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ selected_business.business_name }}</div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated and selected_business %}
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="business_slug" value="{{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        {% if request.user == selected_business.seller and selected_user %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ selected_user.username }}">
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="flex-grow-0 py-3 px-4 border-top">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input name="content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


i dont understand, what you want to achieve.

I don't want the messages to show up when I click on a certain message with someone, but for some reason, the _str_ method from Message model pops up as a django message, need to know how to get rid of them.

Where do these messages show up?  What should happen when a button is clicked?  Add your template, that might help me understand what the issue is.  The __str__ is what Django uses to print a Message to the template, admin panel, everywhere.

I have added my user_messages.html. The django messages only show up when a message is selected.

On which place in template you see message.str() ? If you send a get without business slug you get empty messages. They "show up" only when business_slug exists in GET.

I see the message.str message on my user_messages.html page. Yes you are right, they only show up when business_slug exists in GET. So how do I get rid of them?
